# How to associate data from one object with another

Tags: angular, typescript

So I am using the TMDB API and trying to display the movies along with their genres. I have two objects where I subscribe the movies and genres details on each, as following:

```
  listTrendingMovies() {
    this.listMediaService.listTrendingMovies().subscribe((res) => {
      this.trendingMovies = res['results'];
    });
  }
```

The "results" is an object and it has an array with the respective ID for each movie, [as shown in their documentation](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/trending/get-trending).

To fetch the data and subscribe it on my genresList:

```
  listGenres(){
    this.listMediaService.listMovieGenres().subscribe((res) =>{
      this.genresList = res['genres']
    })
  }
```

The "genres" is another object and it has an array with the respective ID for each genre, [as shown in their documentation.](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/genres/get-movie-list)

I created a function that gives me the name for each genre based on the id:

```
  findGenre(genreId){
    this.genresList.forEach((obj) =>{
      if (genreId == obj.id){
        this.genreName = obj.name
        console.log(obj.name)
      }
    })
  }
```

Sadly, that's the further I could go. Now, I have a method to get a specific genre through its ID,  both of the objects have the data for movie and genres details, but I could not find a way to associate each movie I call on my component.html (using ngFor) with the genres object.

I would appreaciate any help

Comment: How have you tried to associate them so far? What does your template look like?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're new to programming itself, not just Angular? I'll go with that and help you out with the simplified version of what you're hoping to achieve - I'll omit the UI side as your details seem to focus on how to find and filter rather than display.

Assuming the task is, for example, a drop-down of genres for the user to pick, which then results in a list of films that match that genre?

Final assumptions are that you have the UI in place for the user to pick the genre (as you have the method to find it), and that, given a list of films, the UI will display it.

With all that in place:

1. JS/TS provides simpler methods for finding items in an array rather than looping yourself.

```js
public findGenre(genreId: number): Genre | undefined {
    return this.genres.find(x => x.id === genreId);
}
```

`.find` will either return the first found value that matches the criteria or `undefined` if nothing found.

2. For the crux of your question, how to find films with a given genre now that you have it.

Well, for a start, you actually don't need to retrieve the genre before finding the films! The API docs you linked say that the films themselves contain a list of the genre IDs - which you already have; no need to worry about finding the genre because you won't be using it anyway!

Assuming you have some 'showFilms' array which is what is used in your template's *ngFor to list the films to show to the user...

```js
public setFilmsForGenreId(genreId: number): void {
    this.showFilms = this.films.filter(x => x.genre_ids.includes(genreId));
}
```

The `.filter` method will do the same as the `.find`, but return multiple results (or an empty list) that match the criteria. The criteria, in this case, being that the film's `genre_ids` array `.includes` the given genre ID value.

So now that's much simpler; on selection of a genre via the assumed drop down list, the `setFilmsForGenreId` method can be called with that picked ID. That method will set the `showFilms` array with whatever films have that genre and your template can `*ngFor="let film of showFilms"` over that to display them in a lovely list for the user.